# ImageView collision detection

Tags: android, imageview, collision

I tried following methods but none of them working as expected:

1.

```
if(objectY >= object2Y && objectY <= object2Y + object2.getheight() && objectX <= object2X + object.getWidth() && objectX >= object2X){
System.out.println("collision")
}
```

2. The `Rect.intersects(r1,r2)` method which others have explained in other questions.

I tried the following code:

```
Rect rc1 = new Rect();
object.getDrawingRect(rc1);
Rect rc2 = new Rect();
object2.getDrawingRect(rc2);
if (Rect.intersects(rc1, rc2) { System.out.println("collision") }
```

In the 1st case it is detecting collision on the basis of x-axis only and in the 2nd case it is detecting collision as soon as the program runs.

can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
if (ruY >= (screenHeight -rp.getHeight()*2)&& ruY <= (screenHeight - rp.getHeight()) && ruX <= rpX + rp.getWidth() && ruX >= rpX )

    {
```

System.out.println("collision");
}

Comment: Okay, I think I don't know how to post here. But hope it is understandable.